# Visual Basic Command Line

Tags: vb.net, command-line

I am making a program with visual basic. I know how to read text from a txt file but I want to use the Context Menu: [Context Menu Tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/). I am going to make a key like this: `C:\\Program Files\\Something\\something.exe %1` Where `something.exe` is my program. `%1` is the file which the menu was used on: [image: Example Image].

How do I make my program retrieve the file that was passed and read the text from it? Normally I would do this:

```
Dim fileReader As System.IO.StreamReader
fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("C:\\testfile.txt")
Dim stringReader As String
stringReader = fileReader.ReadLine()
MsgBox("The first line of the file is " & stringReader)
```

**Edit**: I also want to do it in a Windows Form Application so I can use forms.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate because it is using the context menu which could be different.

Comment: It is a duplicate, because you receive the command line parameters exactly the same way when the context menu item is executed. Windows sends the filename in the parameter that you've (correctly) identified as `%1`,

Comment: I also want to do it in a Windows Form Application so I can use forms but, that one is using the command line application. Editing

Comment: It's **still** received the same way in a WinForms app if it's provided via a context menu. Windows **always** passes the filename as the first parameter when it executes a context menu handler. Why aren't you listening?

Comment: I know that. I am just wondering if you know ow to do this with a Windows Form Application

Comment: **Exactly the same way**, for the **third time**. ***EXACTLY*** the same way. What part of **exactly the same way** is difficult for you to understand? Read my very first comment again, particularly the second sentence. That applies to a console application, a WinForms application, a WPF application, a batch file, or a PowerShell script. They **all** get it in the same way if a context menu handler executes them.

Comment: Sorry I forgot that forms still used Subs. xD

Comment: *Ken White is on fire. Your defense is terrified....*